# Python - string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, string

I apologize if this is a basic fix and the length of the post, but I am new to Python. I've also included a large chunk of the script for context purposes.

I am using a script to pull scanning data from JSON into a MySQL DB. The script was working fine until an update was released.

Now when I run the script I receive the error:

for result in resultc['response']['results']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Before this update I knew the data types for each value, but this has changed and I cannot pinpoint where. Is there a way to convert each value to be recognized as a string?

```
# Send the cumulative JSON and then populate the table
cumresponse, content = SendRequest(url, headers, cumdata)
resultc = json.loads(content)
off = 0
print "\nFilling cumvulndata table with vulnerabilities from the cumulative database. Please wait..."
for result in resultc['response']['results']:
    off += 1
    print off, result
    cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO cumvulndata(
offset,pluginName,repositoryID,
severity,pluginID,hasBeenMitigated,
dnsName,macAddress,familyID,recastRisk,
firstSeen,ip,acceptRisk,lastSeen,netbiosName,
port,pluginText,protocol) VALUES 

(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,(FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)),%s,%s,(FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)),%s,%s,    %s,%s)""" , (off,result["pluginName"],result["repositoryID"]),result["severity"]),
result["pluginID"]), result["hasBeenMitigated"]),result["dnsName"],
result["macAddress"],result["familyID"]),result["recastRisk"]),
result["firstSeen"],result["ip"],result["acceptRisk"],result["lastSeen"],
result["netbiosName"],result["port"],result["pluginText"],result["protocol"]))
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `resultc['response']` is a `String` and that you cannot reference the `results` index of it (because strings are technically a tuple of characters). Please post the output of  `print(resultc)`

Comment: I will post the output in the morning, thank you.

Comment: try to find your list and then find an integer to index it with.

Comment: Response "{'status': '200', 'content-length': '239', 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'server': 'Apache', 'pragma': 'no-store', 'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'date': 'Fri, 15 Feb 2013 15:11:41 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}"
Conetnt "{"type":"regular","request_id":"1","response":"","error_code":146,"error_msg":"Invalid parameters specified for vuln query.\nFilter 'lastSeen' must be in the following format: <end day>:<start day>.\n","warnings":[],"timestamp":1360941101}"
<type 'dict'>
<type 'unicode'>

Comment: There was quite a bit of data before that but it is too much to post

Answer (score 1):

Put this before the for loop to work out which object is the string (I guess it's probably the second one)

```
print type(resultc)
print type(resultc['response'])
```

Comment: I will try this in the morning and post the result, my server got shutdown for maintenance.